# Active Job simultaneously jobs - rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activejob

I am quite confused on how I should proceed if I want to handle multiple jobs at the same time.

I have a rails API for which one of the task is fetching other apis. This tasks take a long time because it does many call to other apis.
At the current moment what I did is create an active job and calling the perform_later method (from a controller) when someone wants to launch this task.
However if multiple users want to ask for this task to run, what I understood is that each task will be queued and processed one by one which I dont really want because it means that some users will have to wait a long time.

What I would like is if I have different users asking for this specific task is that active job takes care of more than one task at a time.

**How should I proceed?**

I tried to switch from perform_later method to perform however when one task is running, if I try to call my rails api, my request is on hold until the first task is finished.
Any clarification or help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: According to my knowledge, active job is the only way to implement background jobs. Try using 'sidekiq' adapter.

Comment: You need multiple background (or sidekiq) workers to handle these multiple processes in parallel. I suppose you're testing your code on your local machine and you haven't configured your application. [This article](https://www.toptal.com/ruby/ruby-concurrency-and-parallelism-a-practical-primer) could help you.

Comment: I would also suggest using a [queue adapter](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.1/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters.html) such as [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq). The `concurrency` setting in Sidekiq allows you to specify how many jobs can be run simultaneously, and spawning multiple workers can also allow you to run more simultaneous jobs (at cost).

Answer (score 0):

Rails comes with a background processing framework called [Active Job](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html). It lets you tell rails you want a bit of code to be executed by another process (not the app server). Since there are many options as to how background jobs can be handled ActiveJob is just an API for handling background jobs and the actual work is done by an [Adapter](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.1/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters.html), very similar to the way ActiveJob is just an API and the real writing to the database is done by different adapters which know how to talk to different DBs.

Out of the box Active Job will use the Async adapter, which is good for development since it will spin up a worker (with [Concurrent Ruby](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby)) with no extra setup required. The bad part is that it will only spin up 1 of these workers, and that is why you are seeing your jobs get picked up one by one.

The Async adapter isn't designed to run more than one worker at a time, and the queue it uses to store your jobs while the worker gets time to perform them isn't persisted so you will lose enqueued jobs each time you restart your server.

Your will need to switch to another queue adapter that lets you spin up as many workers as you want so you can have jobs running simultaneously. I recommend using [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) if you expect to have few jobs and don't want to add complexity to your project, since it will use your DB to store the job queue. If you expect to have many (hundreds) of jobs enqueued at a time then something like Sidekiq, or Resque will be better since they move the job queue to a Redis server.

Each adapter has it's own way of starting workers, so read the documentation for the adapter you land on to spin up as many workers as you need. Eg. `RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job -n 2 start` in DelayedJob